# Define a range in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

So I have the variable tstrng in a For loop and I want to set it equal to Columns C to Z at row "i", i being defined by the for loop iteration.  I wrote the definition like this but the range keeps coming up as being empty and throwing a Runtime error. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
tstrng = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Range("C" & i, "Z")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `tstrng = wb1.Sheets("SourceData").Range("C" & i, "Z" & i)`

If `i` is 1 that will set `tstrng` to Range `C1:Z1` in your `SourceData` worksheet.